# Elevation is not working in PopupWindow Android

Tags: android, android-popupwindow, android-elevation

I am using `PopupWindow` in my android app and its working fine. But I have to add `elevation` to it but its not working. Here is how I am doing it

View to show in popup window `popup_view_order_status`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_xlarge"
    android:elevation="@dimen/margin_large"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_large">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/lbl_order_status" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbAccepted"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/text_xxlarge_m"
            android:text="@string/lbl_accepted"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbRejected"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/text_xxlarge_m"
            android:text="@string/lbl_rejected"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbOutForDelivery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/text_xxlarge_m"
            android:text="@string/lbl_out_for_delivery"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/rbReadyForPickup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/text_xxlarge_m"
            android:text="@string/lbl_ready_for_pickup"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbCompleted"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/text_xxlarge_m"
            android:text="@string/lbl_completed"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I am setting it up in activity

```
    val inflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val popupView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_view_order_status, null)
    val width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    val height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    val focusable = true // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable)
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(binding.btnOrderStatusChange, Gravity.RIGHT, 50, -binding.btnOrderStatusChange.measuredHeight / 2)
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE))
    popupWindow.elevation = 120F
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try following:

1. Use `CardView` as your content root `View`, it has `cardElevation` attribute for customizing shadow.

- **Keep in mind that in order to make the `CardView` shadow visible, you must add some margin to it, and to make the margin visible, you have to add one more `View` to wrap the `CardView`, you can use `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`.**

3. Call `popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null)` to remove built-in background.

Demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlWX4kIDI6Q